# Is this sentence "he hopes for taking his life, to which he has no right" correct?

Tags: grammar

My intention is: He hopes for taking his life, but he shouldn't have the right to do so.

Is "which" used correctly?

Comment: Proof-reading is off topic for this site. But "hopes for taking" is wrong and the rest of the sentence says he has no right to his life, not taking his life. Needs rewording.

Comment: You haven't even used "which"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence you provided does not convey the intended meaning.
The correct sentence to convey the idea can be :

> He wishes to take his own life, but he shouldn't have the right to do so.